# Fault Injection - delays and aborts not working in Istio

Tags: config, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I've configured Istio to delay/abort http-traffic with 30 seconds to my catalogue-service, yet when i refresh my page, the catalogue shows without any delays.

This is a setup in Google's GKE. I'm using the sock-shop demo to test several aspects of Istio's functionality.

My current setup is as follows: This is my yaml-file containing all the services and deployments (shortened to the configuration of Catalogue and the front-end, which uses the catalogue):

```
#################################################
# Catalogue-db
#################################################
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: catalogue-db-v1
  labels:
    name: catalogue-db
    version: v1
  namespace: sock-shop
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: catalogue-db
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: catalogue-db
        image: weaveworksdemos/catalogue-db:0.3.0
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: fake_password
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
            value: socksdb
        ports:
        - name: mysql
          containerPort: 3306
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: catalogue-db
  labels:
    name: catalogue-db
  namespace: sock-shop
spec:
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    name: catalogue-db
---
######################################################
#Catalogue
######################################################
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: catalogue
  labels:
    name: catalogue
    version: v1
  namespace: sock-shop
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: catalogue
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: catalogue
        image: weaveworksdemos/catalogue:0.3.5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 10001
          capabilities:
            drop:
              - all
            add:
              - NET_BIND_SERVICE
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: catalogue
  labels:
    name: catalogue
  namespace: sock-shop
spec:
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 80
    name: http-catalogue
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    name: catalogue
---
##############################################
# Front-End
##############################################
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: front-end-v1
  labels:
     name: front-end
     version: v1
  namespace: sock-shop
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: front-end
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: front-end
        image: weaveworksdemos/front-end:0.3.12
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8079
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 10001
          capabilities:
            drop:
              - all
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: front-end-v2
  labels:
     name: front-end
     version: v2
  namespace: sock-shop
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: front-end
        version: v2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: front-end
        image: vinayakinfrac/front-end:0.3.12
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8079
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 10001
          capabilities:
            drop:
              - all
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: front-end
  labels:
    name: front-end
  namespace: sock-shop
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8079
    name: http-front-end
    nodePort: 30001
  selector:
    name: front-end
```

This is the destinationrule for my catalogue:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: catalogue
  namespace: sock-shop
spec:
  host: catalogue
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
```

And this is the virtualservice, which includes the fault-injection:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: catalogue
  namespace: sock-shop
spec:
  hosts:
  - catalogue
  http:
  - fault:
      delay:
        fixedDelay: 30s
        percent: 100
    route:
    - destination:
        host: catalogue.sock-shop.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
```

Comment: Actually, i've just managed to get some progress on this. I've added destinationrules and virtualservices for ALL my services, and this seems to produce the correct results. I'll post an answer once i've found out which virtualservices/destinationrules contribute to the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it was a mistake on my part. I've tried again with the same configurations as posted in the original question, and it works now.